# How to place a div slightly over an image using bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, css-float, bootstrap-grid

[div nudged slightly over an image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ePRD.png)

I have attached a picture above of what I am trying to do...
I would like to place a div slightly over an image - which is easy to do - but I want to achieve this using bootstrap. Or, using as much of the bootstrap grid as I can, so that these two objects are totally responsive.

This is the code that does what I want, but I want to do this using bootstrap -- using bootstrap is my primary goal.

```
<div style="position:relative">
        <img src="img/1.jpg" alt="" />
        <div style="position:absolute;left:25%;top:50%;border:solid;">
            <h1>This text is on top of the image</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried to achieve with bootstrap here is my code. I did not write media query for extra small devices because it depends on you that how you want to style it on that devices.

#### on codepen:

https://codepen.io/jaspal9755/pen/WKvLBX?editors=1100

#### html

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <img class="img-fluid" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/2755/restaurant.jpg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=350" alt="" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="wrap-heading">
            <h1>This text is on top of the image</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

#### css

```
*{
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}
.wrapper{
  position:relative;
  padding:10px;
}
h1{
  border: 2px solid;
  font-size:30px;
  padding:15px;
}
.wrap-heading{
  position:absolute;
  top:40%;
  left:-25%;
}

@media(min-width:767px) and (max-width:992px){
  h1{
    font-size:25px;
  }
}
@media(min-width:576px) and (max-width:768px){
  h1{
    font-size:20px;
  }
}
```